# Filtering with Vue.js, getting the value of an Object

Tags: vue.js

I have a website that uses a filtering system built in Vue.js, it filters properties with "states", "cities" and "type", the code looks like this, it works for states and types but not for cities which come from an Object rather than an Array. I am not sure how to acces the value inside of the Object.

```
<div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
    <div class="cell medium-auto">
        <label for="property-state">STATE</label>
        <select name="property-state" @change="search()" id="property-state">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option v-for="val in terms['property-state']" :value="val.id">{{ val.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="cell medium-auto">
        <label for="city">CITY</label>
        <select name="city" @change="search()" id="city">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option v-for="val in terms ['location']" :value="val.id">{{ val.city }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="cell medium-auto" @change="search()">
        <label for="property-type">PROPERTY TYPE</label>
        <select name="property-type" id="property-type">
            <option value="">All types</option>
            <option v-for="val in terms['property-type']" :value="val.id">{{ val.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am aware that I'm trying to access "location" as if it were an Array but not sure how to do it as it is an Object as seen in the image attached.

The data I am trying to access is structured as follows:

```
location (Object)

   |

   city: "cityName"
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object

Answer (score 0):

In Vue, v-for treats an object and an array in the same way. An array has the same type of values, but an object has a structure that could be different. Use computed properties to save your city name into an array.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object